# How to read stdout (with \r) of process opened with popen

Tags: c, linux

I need to read output of a program that uses carriage returns (\r) to make its output.

I have an old utility with output like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    setvbuf(stdout, (char*)NULL,_IONBF, 0);

    fprintf(stdout, "Start\n");
    for (auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

        fprintf(stdout, "\r%2d", i);
        usleep(100000);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "\nEnd\n");

    return 0;
}
```

So I execute it with popen from my program and I need to trace a progress:

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        return -1;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<FILE, int(*)(FILE*)> filePtr( popen(argv[1], "r"), &pclose );

    int c = fgetc(filePtr.get());
    while (c != EOF); {

        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(filePtr.get());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This work fine only without \r in stdout. Does anybody know is it possible to execute a process and read all output even with carriaage return symbols?

Comment: While the first "old utility" program is *almost* plain C, the second program you show is C++.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the carriage-return `'\r'` isn't really anything special, it's how you *handle* it that makes it different.

A terminal program uses it to control cursor position, but that's only done inside the terminal program itself, it's not "built-in" in the `'\r'` character.

If you want to handle it in a special way then you need to create your program that way.

Comment: So It's mean I can read '\r' with fgetc and just ignore it, thanks.